# Parsing the Azure Storage Account connection string with Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.android, azure-storage

I'm creating an app that I need to connect to an Azure Storage Account which requires you to implement a connection string in the app settings consisting of the Account Name and the Account Key. The connection string is then parsed through the CloudStorageAccount class.

I figured I could get the string by using the GetValue Method of the AppSettingsReader Class as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698509/settings-must-be-of-the-form-name-value-no-idea-what-to-do/36700087#36700087), but I can't use the System.Configuration Namespace with Xamarin.Android because it targets Monodroid.

How else can I implement the connection string so I can parse it through the CloudStorageAccount?

Answer (score 1):

The Xamarin library does not support authentication using account key, so the connection string isn’t very useful. There are no dependencies on the configuration settings so you can put credentials where ever you want.

Comment: That's kinda what I figured out. I put them in a class.